# .h file not found when integrating IQKeyboardManager

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, cocoapods, uitextview, iqkeyboardmanager

I tried simply adding

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
```

...to my Podfile. Then I

```
#import 'IQKeyboardManager.h'
```

But the .h file was not found. So I dropped in the the 'IQKeyboardManager' directory to my Resources Files but the header is still not found. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to your problem?

Comment: i had added some code to disable arm64 code in podfile for simulator builds- caused this problem - but haven't found  proper solution to other problem.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using single-quotes in your Xcode project.

You should use double-quotes:
`#import "IQKeyboardManager.h"`